# How do I get butterknife to recognize R2 in a library test class?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-library, butterknife

I understand that Butterknife binds views such as TextViews- `@BindView(R.id.test_status) EditText txtStatus;`- As well, it binds for a click event -`@OnClick(R.id.login_task)`-. I even understand that currently Butterknife can be used to bind views ect. in a library with the proper dependencies declared within the build.Gradle file. I know through research that the views in a library must be final or constant within the library to work properly with butterknife. Each of these scenarios I have working within this application. I even understand that because I am in a library, the usage of R2.java as opposed to R.java when binding views -

```
@BindView(R2.id.test_status)
EditText txtStatus;
```

What I do not understand is, why does butterknife not recognise views in a library test class?

```
Package name
com.test-lib.sso(androidTest)

build.gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'


ext {

    MAVEN_URL = System.getenv('MAVEN_URL') ?: System.getProperty("MAVEN_URL")
    MAVEN_USERID = System.getenv('MAVEN_USERID') ?: System.getProperty("MAVEN_USERID")
    MAVEN_PASSWD = System.getenv('MAVEN_PASSWD') ?: System.getProperty("MAVEN_PASSWD")
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.0'
    }

}
   dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'


    api 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta02'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.4.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    api 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'

 }
```

In my test class.

```
import com.lib.sso.test.R;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_main_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
@BindView(R.id.test_status) EditText txtStatus;
@BindView(R.id.env_spinner) AppCompatSpinner spinner;

 @OnClick(R2.id.test_login)
 public void startNewActivity(View v){
    startActivityForResult(NewActivity.getLoginIntent(activity), REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN);
 }
```

XML in layout

```
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/test_login"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="10sp"
           android:text="Sign In"/>
```

In the `@BindView`, Android Studio wants the `R.id.test_login` to be constant which I could do by declaring `@BindView(R2.id.test_login)` except the constant variable is not generated in R2.java.

When I migrate the butterknife calls to R2, the variable becomes red and is not recognised. When I search within the R2.java, I will not find that variable at all, mainly because it has not been generated.
So, How do I get butterknife to recognize R2 in a library test class?

Comment: You have 2 times the butterknife dependencies one with "api" and one with "implementation". Also please give more information... Do you have 1 app module and 1 library module or you have multiple library module? Anyway you need to use R inside your application module activities/fragment/ecc.. and R2 inside your library module. Also I read that butterknife doesn't work well with kotlin.

Comment: OK so One is classpath, the other is the dependency for implementation. I was trying to develop Espresso tests for the library I am working with. The Butterknife works as expected within the app and library, which is where the R2.java has generated id's. However, in any of the test classes, the R2.java doesn't generate the views and therefore cannot bind views.

Comment: Sorry I never tryed it inside test classes :/ Anyway if it cannot generate R2 normally is because the "plugin" and/or the "annotationProcessor" aren't setted. So I suppose you need to add the plugin somewhere on the test dependencies.
Remember to "clean project" + "re-build project", I had similar problem in an application with 2 module library with 1 which depend from the other. I solved to generate R2 by adding plugin and annotationProcessor on the second library module :/ also I cleaned and rebuilt 2/3 times before it worked xD

Comment: Oh also check the import on the top of your test class, maybe u are importing R2 from the library, try to delete it and re-import it to see if you have more import options. 

There is another way you can maybe use to solve your problem: you can add the views ids you put on the layout inside an "ids" xml resource inside the values folder of your library module. This way when you use R2 as library module inside the test class it should resolve it right.